# how to use jquery plugin news ticker in sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, branding

hi i want to use jquery plugin news ticker in sharepoint 2013 
 for last news how can I use this ?the code is available in below url
http://www.jqueryscript.net/animation/Flexible-Customizable-jQuery-News-Ticker-Plugin-Easy-Ticker.html

Comment: Look [here is a cool Tesla X](https://www.tesla.com/modelx), can anybody tell me how I can build one myself? StackOverflow is about helping you with coding problems, we are not here to do your job. If you don't have the skills yet to do your job then do what all of us did. We roamed the internet for weeks, reading blogs, trying pieces of code, slowly getting comfortable with coding [in SharePoint]

Comment: have you tried the following tutorial https://chrisstahl.wordpress.com/2011/05/28/display-news-pages-with-cqwp-%E2%80%93-part-i/

Answer (score 0):

Start by learning to use the CEWP (Content Editor WebPart)

https://www.google.nl/search?q=youtube+cewp